# Sharepoint 2013 designer's ribbon doesn't have the "Stage" feature

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow, ribbon, feature

[image]

I discovered that my SharePoint foundation 2013 designer doesn't have the stage feature in the top ribbon. How do I enable this feature?

If my version isn't supposed to have this feature, are there any alternatives to this? I need to use the feature "transition to stage" specifically.

This is how my current ribbon looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a SharePoint 2010 workflow? You can check the workflow type in Workflow Settings.

[image]

If you want to use the feature "transition to stage", you can use a SharePoint 2013 workflow. The only platform available when you first install SharePoint Server 2013 is the SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform. SharePoint 2013 Workflow requires SharePoint Server 2013 and Workflow Manager.

Workflow Manager must be downloaded and installed separately from SharePoint Server 2013. It does not install automatically when you install SharePoint Server 2013.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj658588.aspx

Comment: Sorry for my carelessness. I did not notice that you are using SharePoint foundation.

The solution is for SharePoint Server. However SharePoint foundation does not support Workflow 2013.

Since SharePoint 2010 workflow is a sequential workflow represents a series of steps, maybe you need to develop a state machine workflow using code. A state machine workflow represents a set of states, transitions, and actions. The steps in a state machine workflow execute asynchronously. This means that they are not necessarily performed one after another.

Comment: Reference:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508985.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396